# Is it possible to put an image over all other layout elements (Buttons...)

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a login screen with a Login button... I also have a ViewPager with some images. When I slide the ViewPager the image covers some login elements, but not all.

Right now I use the `android:background = "myImage"`
I also tried to use `android:foreground = "myImage"`, but somehow it does not cover two of my buttons.

Here is some code from my main Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="415dp"
                android:layout_height="277dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="540dp"
                android:src="@drawable/jus_login_two"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.558" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mainActivity_username"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#32756e"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="E-Mail-Adresse"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.364" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mainActivity_password"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#32756e"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Passwort"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainActivity_username"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="OR"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainActivity_errorMessage"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainActivity_errorMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.658" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mainActivity_login"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#32756e"
                android:text="Anmelden"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.532" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mainActivity_continueWithout"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="ohne anmelden fortfahren"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#32756e"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainActivity_createNewAccount"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.075" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mainActivity_createNewAccount"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="#3b5998"
                android:text="Neues Konto erstellen"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.859"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mainActivity_forgotPassword"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Passwort vergessen?"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#32756e"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.71" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="150sp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvText"
                android:background="#A9A9A9"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.756" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="150sp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvText"
                android:background="#A9A9A9"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvText"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.757" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_rememberPwdUsr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="E-Mail-Adresse und Passwort speichern?"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.434"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.597" />

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/therealPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the code where I set the image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/jus_slide_one"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better to provide a visual explanation of what is happening or at least some code, currently it is very difficult to actually diagnose your issue.

Comment: @Max is it better now?

Comment: I think the issue here is that your layout need some refactoring. For a start I would not recommend using a ConstraintLayout as a surrogate ImageView. What are you trying to achieve? A situation where the image will cover the ENTIRE page?

Comment: @Max yes I want an Image that covers the whole page also the buttons somehow it is working, but the login and create_new account button are over the image

Comment: Actually, this is now sounding like it could be related to the elevation of these buttons, have you tried to set the button elevations to 0 or played with the z value of the view pager, I think this might be of use.

Comment: @Max thank you I just solved it I had some wrong values...